# Extract a number from a Listbox item

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm new to programming and cannot find a way to get a number back from a listbox.

I'm trying to extract just a number from a selected item in a listbox.

The type of information in the listbox is "Travel: €15.66 on 12/3/13.

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    decimal inputdata = (decimal)lbxDisplay.SelectedItems;

    //Remove selected items from Listbox
    lbxDisplay.Items.RemoveAt(lbxDisplay.SelectedIndex);

    //Update Expenses Total text block
    tblkTotal.Text = string.Format("Total Expenses\t{0}", expense.DeductedTotal();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If information in the listbox is "Travel: €15.66 on 12/3/13", do you want "15.66" only?

Comment: @JohnnyC why do you want  it you just removing the item, you didn't even use that value

Comment: Because it's the remove function?

Comment: I have a running total expenses that must revise downwards as items are removed from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Regex`  on the `SelecteItem` to extract  the number

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var sel = listBox1.SelectedItem;
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"[0-9\.]+");
          var res =   reg.Match(sel.ToString());
        //if you want to compute the total 
        double total = 0; 
        var allItems = listBox1.SelectedItems;
        foreach (var item in allItems)
        {
            double dres = double.Parse(reg.Match(sel.ToString()).Value);
            total = dres + total; 

        }
        tblkTotal.Text = string.Format("Total Expenses\t{0}", total);

    }
```

Just one trick if you want the total of `SelectedItems`  and not only one item you should do something like this in your form's constructor

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to get the desired Number/Price would use splitting:

```
var inputDataParts = inputdata.Split(' ');
```

Now the second part should be the price

```
string price = inputDataParts[1];
```

Now get rid of the Euro-Sign and trim it:

```
price = price.Replace('€', '').Trim();
```

Now price should hold "15.66" - convert it if needed.

The harder way would be using RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like that (look there to find how to use a regex http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string pattern = @"[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? ";
```

Then, you just have to convert your matched string into a double :

```
double value = Convert.ToDouble(matchedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
string str = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
int startIndex = str.IndexOf('€');
str = str.Substring(startIndex+1).Split(' ')[0].Trim();
decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create expense class:

```
public class Expense
{
    public Expense(string name, decimal amount, DateTime date)
    {
        Name = name;
        Amount = amount;
        Date = date;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}: €{1} {2}", 
                             Name, Amount, Date.ToShortDateString());
    }
}
```

Then bind listbox to list of expense objects - they all will be displayed in format `Travel: €15.66 on 12/3/13`:

```
var expenses = new List<Expense> {
    new Expense("Travel", 16.5M, new DateTime(2013, 12, 3)),
    new Expense("Sports", 13.0M, new DateTime(2013, 12, 4)),
};

listBox1.DataSource = expenses;
```

Getting amount of selected expense will be easy, because selected item will be `Expense` object:

```
var expense = (Expense)listBox1.SelectedItem;
// expense.Amount
```

NOTE: Instead of overriding `ToString()` functionality you can create some `Display` or `Description` property which will return formatted string, and specify this property as `DisplayMember` name for listBox.